# li:hover ul works in Chrome always and IE9 "sometimes"

Tags: asp.net, css, drop-down-menu, hover, internet-explorer-9

I'm attempting a classic CSS Hover Dropdown Menu. I'd like to say that the CSS is working just fine since it looks the way I want in Chrome. However, it works correctly in IE9 when I have it as a standalone page but NOT when I use it on the Site.Master.

Below is my HTML markup which works in IE9:

```
<%@ Page Title="Part Info" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false"
CodeBehind="Part_Info.aspx.vb" Inherits="MOO.Part_Info" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>    </title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
    <div class="page">

<!-- Start css3menu.com BODY section -->
<ul id="css3menu1" class="topmenu">
    <li class="topmenu">    <a href="#" title="Admin" style="height:24px;line-height:24px;">    <span>Admin    </span>    </a>
            <ul>
            <li>    <a href="AdminDashBoard.aspx" title="Dashboard">Dashboard    </a>    </li>
            <li>    <a href="Feedback.aspx" title="Feedback">    <span>Feedback    </span>    </a>    </li>
            <li>    <a href="MOO_Updates.aspx" title="MOO Report Updates">MOO Report Updates    </a>    </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="topmenu">    <a href="#" title="Orders" style="height:24px;line-height:24px;">    <span>Orders    </span>    </a>
        <ul>
            <li>    <a href="Default.aspx" title="Allocation">Allocation    </a>    </li>
            <li>    <a href="CurrentMonthHolds.aspx" title="Holds">    <span>Holds    </span>    </a>    </li>
            <li>    <a href="SpecialProjA.aspx" title="Project Status">Project Status    </a>    </li>
            <li>    <a href="ShipPastDue.aspx" title="Past Due">    <span>Past Due    </span>    </a>    </li>
            <li>    <a href="Backorder_Impact.aspx" title="Backorders">    <span>Backorders    </span>    </a>    </li>
            <li class="sublast">    <a href="/Shortages.aspx" title="Shortages">Shortages    </a>    </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<!-- End css3menu.com BODY section -->

    <asp:Label ID="Alert_Label" runat="server">    </asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then, when I attempt to use the same Menu HTML and CSS within a Site.Master, I don't get any hover action. My Site.Master HTML:

```
    <%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Site.master.vb" Inherits="MOO.Site" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>    </title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Site_Master_Form" runat="server">
    <div class="page">

       <div class="header">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>
                Manufacturing/Operations Online (MOO)
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="loginDisplay" >
                <%= "Welcome, " & Replace(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER"), "BOUMATIC\", "")%>
            </div>
            <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
                 <img id="img_CowView" class="CowView" src="Styles/img/CowView.png" usemap="#CowViewMap" alt="" style="border: none;"/>
                     <map id="id_CowViewMap" name="CowViewMap">
                          <area shape="circle" coords="120,30,20" alt="" href="#" ondblclick='open_udderground("Udderground/default.aspx")'/>
                     </map>
                 <input id="btn_Part_Info" type="button" value="Part Info" onclick='open_win("Part_Info.aspx")' runat="server" style="float:right;"/>
                 <input id="btn_Archive_Notes" type="button" value="Archive Notes" onclick='open_win("ArchiveNotes.aspx")' runat="server" style="float:right;"/>
<!-- Start css3menu.com BODY section -->
<ul id="css3menu1" class="topmenu">
<li class="topmenu">    <a href="#" title="Admin" style="height:24px;line-height:24px;">    <span>Admin    </span>    </a>
        <ul>
        <li>    <a href="AdminDashBoard.aspx" title="Dashboard">Dashboard    </a>    </li>
        <li>    <a href="Feedback.aspx" title="Feedback">    <span>Feedback    </span>    </a>    </li>
        <li>    <a href="MOO_Updates.aspx" title="MOO Report Updates">MOO Report Updates    </a>    </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="topmenu">    <a href="#" title="Orders" style="height:24px;line-height:24px;">    <span>Orders    </span>    </a>
    <ul>
        <li>    <a href="Default.aspx" title="Allocation">Allocation    </a>    </li>
        <li>    <a href="CurrentMonthHolds.aspx" title="Holds">    <span>Holds    </span>    </a>    </li>
        <li>    <a href="SpecialProjA.aspx" title="Project Status">Project Status    </a>    </li>
        <li>    <a href="ShipPastDue.aspx" title="Past Due">    <span>Past Due    </span>    </a>    </li>
        <li>    <a href="Backorder_Impact.aspx" title="Backorders">    <span>Backorders    </span>    </a>    </li>
        <li class="sublast">    <a href="/Shortages.aspx" title="Shortages">Shortages    </a>    </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
<!-- End css3menu.com BODY section -->

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Again, I'm using the same CSS, the same web.config, and the same menu HTML. Why, oh why, can I make IE9 acknowledge an li:hover ul on one page but not the other???

Thanks,
Rob

Adding applicable CSS:

```
/*  CSS Menu Items  
----------------------------------------------------------*/
ul#css3menu1, ul#css3menu1 ul{
margin:0;list-style:none;padding:0;background-color:#0071B9;
}
li ul
{
/*visibility: hidden;*/
display: none;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 100%;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
background-color: #0071B9;
border-radius: 0px;
-moz-border-radius: 0px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px;
padding: 0;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
li:hover ul
{
/*visibility: visible;*/
display: block;
opacity:1;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

ul#css3menu1 li{
position:relative;display:block;white-space:nowrap;
/*font-size:0;*/
float:left;}

ul#css3menu1 li:hover{
z-index:1;}

ul#css3menu1 ul ul{
position:absolute;left:100%;top:0;-moz-box-shadow:#585858 0px 0px 1px;-webkit-box-shadow:#585858 0px 0px 1px;box-shadow:#585858 0px 0px 1px;}

ul#css3menu1{
/*font-size:0;*/
z-index:999;
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
zoom:1;padding:0;border-radius:0px;-moz-border-radius:0px;-webkit-border-radius:0px;
/**display:inline;*/}
* html ul#css3menu1 li a{
display:inline-block;}

ul#css3menu1>li{
margin:0;}
ul#css3menu1 a:active, ul#css3menu1 a:focus{
outline-style:none;}

ul#css3menu1 a{ 
display:block;vertical-align:middle;text-align:left;text-decoration:none;
font:bold 18px Verdana; color:#FFFFFF; cursor:pointer;padding:23px 18px 26px;
background-color:#0071B9;
background-repeat:repeat;border-width:0px;border-style:none;border-color:; }


ul#css3menu1 ul li{
float:none;margin:0;}

ul#css3menu1 ul a
{
text-align: left;
padding: 8px 15px;
background-color: #0071B9;
border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #4A4A4A;
border-radius: 0px;
-moz-border-radius: 0px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
-o-transition: all 0.5s;
font: bold 14px  Verdana;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;
}

ul#css3menu1 li:hover>a,ul#css3menu1 li a.pressed{
border-style:none;color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;}
ul#css3menu1 img{
border:none;vertical-align:middle;margin-right:23px;}
ul#css3menu1 ul span{
background-image:none;padding-right:8px;}
ul#css3menu1 ul li:hover>a,ul#css3menu1 ul li a.pressed{
background-color:#F29233;border-style:solid;border-color:#4A4A4A;color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;}
ul#css3menu1 li.topmenu>a{
background-color:#0071B9;border-width:3px 0 0 0;border-style:solid;border-color:transparent transparent transparent transparent;border-radius:0px;-moz-border-radius:0px;-webkit-border-radius:0px;}
ul#css3menu1 li.topmenu:hover>a,ul#css3menu1 li.topmenu a.pressed{
background-color:#F29233;border-style:solid;border-color:#0071B9 transparent transparent transparent;}
ul#css3menu1 li.sublast>a{
border-width:0px;}
/* CSS fallback */
ul#css3menu1 li:hover > ul.child  {
display: block;
}
ul#css3menu1 li:hover > ul.grandchild  { 
display: block;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but there doesn't appear to be any `<li>` elements in the menu in the second example. Secondly, could you post the actual HTML output, instead of the ASP code? Finally, can you post the problem CSS (or, ideally, a testcase on jsfiddle or similar)?

Comment: @OllyHodgson, I added the li elements back in that I had omitted to try and save space. The HTML is identical for the menu on both pages. The actual HTML output from an ASP page is filled with lots of indecipherable code that isn't eye-readable. I posted the CSS. However, I've run the HTML and CSS through jsfiddle and it works just fine in IE9 (http://jsfiddle.net/rv9Yd/).

Comment: OK so if the code works on one page, and on JSFiddle, it suggests it's something specific to this page. In the first it's a direct child of `div.page`, while in the second it's not. Is there any styling on `div.header` or `div.clear.hideSkiplink` that could be affecting it? Perhaps a float clearing issue? Adding an outline using CSS is often a good way to debug those.

Comment: div.header has "position: relative;" (the others are for color and padding) while div.hideSkiplink sets only background-color and width. div.clear is just "clear: both;".

Comment: For giggles, I moved the Menu HTML on the second page up so that it, too, would be a direct child of div.page. It still didn't give me any hover action on the site.master page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it!!!

I had commented out the following line:

```
<!-- Commenting out old !DOCTYPE and <html> tags so that I can use HTML5 as needed
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
-->
```

and left it out of my posting because I didn't think it was relevant. However, when I deleted the line completely (instead of just commenting it out), all of the pages work just fine.

Lesson learned: it appears you cannot comment out some lines carefully enough.

Comment: Ah, yes. If you output *any code at all* (even HTML comments) before the `DOCTYPE`, Internet Explorer will fall back to Quirks Mode, which is a kind of IE5 compatibility mode for legacy web applications.

Comment: Thanks for your help @OllyHodgson. It got me thinking better than I was doing on my own.